# external js file won't run & css 100% properity in titanium appcelerator

Tags: javascript, html, css, titanium, appcelerator

I've just set up my first html appcelerator project and im trying to add a full screen canvas.

So to start I added an external css file using the standard:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
```

and in that css I have the following:

```
canvas {
position: absolute;
width: '100%';
height: Ti.UI.SIZE;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right:0;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

So I'm trying to get it to 100% and I've tried 100% without the quotes, with the quotes, and the Ti.UI.SIZE but it all sizes the same (pic below). But if I set it in px, it works everytime so I figure its something to do with the % in the app view.

[image]

And the other issue is with an external js file. Ive added this to the head tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/main.js"></script>
```

with the contents:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 40, 40);
```

Here is my file structure btw:

[image]

So it just simply doesn't run. If it put the code in script tags in the body on the html file, it works fine so I know it's not the code that's the problem

Any help is appreciated

Comment: just remove the width and height - by using all 4 top left right and left, it should stretch it the full size of the container (if the container is positioned anything other that static).  With regards to the external js, you either need to wrap the code in a document redy constructor or move it to the bottom of your page (before your closing body tag)

Comment: oh of course, i always put the script with 'defer' in it, i forgot this time. That fixed the js issue but for the css, other elements on top of the canvas wont be fullscreen. Its a game so the left touch section will be 50% which i cant do with just top,left etc, i need the percentages

Comment: put the percentages on those then - eg if you want 50% of the screen starting left to right it would be `left:0; right: 50%;`

Comment: Well thats the thing, 100% is interprated as only 100px or so so when i do right: 50%. It wont be accurate. I tried taking out the width and height and it gives the same result so it must be something to do with appcelerater initalising the app dimensions

Comment: you need to create a [mcve] then as we need to see why  your current 100% is only 100px.  with the code and explanation you have provided, there is not enough information to help you, but my guess is the parent of that element is positioned and only 100px wide

Comment: `height: Ti.UI.SIZE;` is TSS syntax and not CSS. Do you really need a canvas/webview? Why not create the views in native Titanium?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [percentages dont work in CSS with titanium appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490005/percentages-dont-work-in-css-with-titanium-appcelerator)

Comment: @miga thats the question i just posted after this lol