# Appcelerator Titanium: CSS width won't work with percentages

Tags: html, css, titanium, appcelerator

I have made a HTML project in Appcelerator. I want a full screen canvas so in CSS I set the property to `100%` (without quotes) which I found out doesn't work with Appcelerator.

I've tried `'100%'` with quotes and `Ti.UI.SIZE` which both size it at a weird size that has the same aspect ratio seen in the image below. I have coloured the canvas green and the body yellow so you know its not the parent that's the problem.

[image]

I have tried searching but HTML only apps don't seem to be too popular with Appcelerator so i cannot find an answer.

My CSS:

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: '100%';
    height: '100%';
    background-color: green;
}

body{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <!-- saved from url=(0047) -->
    <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

          <title>Title</title>

          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
          <script defer type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/main.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please share the html code also

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around the values i.e. `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;`.

Comment: @ElyasEsna html added

Comment: @HiddenHobbes thats what i originally did in the first 2 lines. That wouldnt even give it a value and no green canvas appeared at all

Comment: My bad, looked straight at the code. I'm not familiar with Appcelerator but by it not accepting `100%` is causing the issue.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes with the double quotes? yeh i tried that too

Comment: Stab in the dark, but have you tried `Titanium.UI.FILL` (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-FILL)?

Comment: i just tried that, gives the same size as the one in the picture, i have a feeling its something to do with the orientation since it has the correct aspect ratio

Answer (score 1):

As @HiddenHobbes says in the comment - remove the quotes from your CSS, like so:

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Heres a Fiddle to show it works: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jawgLxk/)

**EDIT:**

vw and vh could possible work too:

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: green;
}
```

vw is for Viewport Width and vh is Viewport Height.

Comment: thats what i meant with 'i set the property to 100% which i found out doesnt work with appcelerator.'.  I set it to 100% without the quotes which didnt give it a size at all. No green canvas was shown. Im pretty sure this is a problem exclusive to appcelerator

Comment: Have you tried `width:100vw;height:100vh;`? It might work :-)

Comment: I havnt, i will try this now

Comment: i tried 100vw with and without quotes and they give the same size. I have a feeling all of these do work but its maybe flipping to portait and back to landscape which is why its keeping its aspect ratio.  I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

This is running fine for me using Titanium 7.1.1.GA and an Android device:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
        #canvas {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: green;
        }

        body {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
            eventHandler();
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', eventHandler);
        }

        function eventHandler() {
            var w = window.innerWidth;
            var h = window.innerHeight;

            document.getElementById("canvas").width = w;
            document.getElementById("canvas").height = h;

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 40, 40);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <WebView id="www" url="/test.html"/>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

index.tss

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
}

"#www":{
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        height: Ti.UI.FILL
}
```

It calculates the size when the body is ready. About the orientation change: you can either add it to the HTML part and recalculate once the device is rotated or you can set a fixed orientation in Titanium e.g. `orientationModes : [Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT]` to prevent the app from going to portrait mode.

Comment: Im currently trying this but it keeps saying file not found for the html. Where did you place it in your app?

Comment: I figured it out, it works for ios but not android. I think im just gonna find another way to make apps with js

Comment: @RachelDockter Hi... you're not making apps if you just use html/css, you're making a website wrapped in a container. I'd recommend really looking into what Titanium offers, or just build a website and wrap that using cordova. If you're sticking with html you'll never get the real "native" feeling you get when building a native app

Comment: @RachelDockter like rene-pot is saying: going the native way makes more sense and offers more possibilities. About Android: I've tested the example above only on Android and it worked fine. Keep in mind that on different devices you might have different WebViews version with different features. Does it load the page on Android or is the whole webview empty?